# How to add a CSS class when page loads and remove it when user clicks on item

Tags: reactjs

I am setting up an active class for my react project using an external library. However, I also want when the page loads to mark the Home tab as active by setting the pink color class. This works, but I am not sure how to remove the pink class after the user clicks on another tab, currently, the Home tab stays pink if the user clicks on another item. I tried to remove the class on the onSelect event but that didn't work. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Menu, MenuItem } from '@progress/kendo-react-layout';

class MenuNavContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: 'pink-class',
    };
  }
  selectedElement = null;
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu onSelect={this.onSelect}>
          <MenuItem
            text="Home"
            data={{ route: '/' }}
            activeClassName="pink-class"
            cssClass={this.state.active}
          />
          <MenuItem text="Products" data={{ route: '/products' }} />
          <MenuItem text="About" data={{ route: '/about' }}>
            <MenuItem text="Team" data={{ route: '/about/team' }} />
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <div style={{ padding: 10 }}>{this.props.children}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onSelect = (event) => {
    if (this.selectedElement !== null) {
      this.selectedElement.classList.remove('pink-class');
    }
    this.selectedElement = event.nativeEvent.target.parentElement;
    this.selectedElement.classList.add('pink-class');
    this.props.history.push(event.item.data.route);
  };
}

export default withRouter(MenuNavContainer);
```

and my CSS:

```
.pink-class {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

And a runnable example in order to showcase this more easily:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zg2pmx-nnzppy?file=app/MenuNavContainer.jsx

How can I mark the Home tab as active when the page loads and then only show the active class once the user has clicked on a different item?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply update your state that holds the class name to be an empty string. No need to set classes using the element on the change handler (this is an anti-pattern anyway).

```
onSelect = (event) => {
  this.setState({active: ''})
  this.props.history.push(event.item.data.route);
};
```

The more I look at this though, the more this seems to be a hack, that you have to provide this class at all..

Now a note more of opinion - I've never used this library before, but for being a "commercial" library that requires a license, I'm very underwhelmed by what I'm seeing. It seems logical to me that there should be a way to specify a `MenuItem` as selected or focused to accomplish this goal (the other tabs do this automatically once clicked), but I do not see anything to meet these requirements. This does not answer your question, but if possible you may search elsewhere for a UI library with a more robust API...